# Chart.js - Scale of secondary Y axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a dataset in Chart.js which I want to display with two scales — one with absolute numbers, one with percentages. For that, I need to use the max value of the first Y axis in my second axis (and then I can process it using `afterDataLimits`). Is there a way to do that without using some kind of hidden second dataset?

```
scales: {
  yAxes: [{
    id: 'y-primary',
    display: true,
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'y-secondary',
    display: true,
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
    },
    position: 'right',
    suggestedMax: ?? // point to y-primary suggested max here?
  }]
}
```

(The percentages don't go to 100, so that I can't just use the secondary axis' default 0-1 scale)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just can set a range for the second y-axis, like this:
Maybe set a value with relation to your first y-axis
--> suggestedMin - suggestedMax

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 50,
                suggestedMax: 100
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

In the first y-axis you can access the values of y-axis by the **callback-function** see below:

```
yAxes : [{
            ticks : {
                       beginAtZero : true,
                       **callback** : function(value,index,values){
                                  yAxesticks = values;
                                  return value;
                            }
                    }
          }]
```

The first value in the array should be the highest one.

Comment: I can do that, but the question is how to get the max tick of the first axis... I can't just take the max data value, since it's generally not the same as the max tick.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! While it wasn't quite what I looked for, I worked the idea out from that.